# Partitioning existing LVM partition?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, fstab, lvm

So currently I am trying to move /var to its own partition, which is well documented across the web. What I am having trouble with is creating a logical volume within the LVM partition. Upon running `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and printing the partition table I receive an output that makes sense to me

[image]

This shows that indeed, there is a ~20GB LVM on my machine. Now to the confusing part. Upon running `sudo vgdisplay` I am greeted with this;

[image]

As shown above, although the volume group's size is 19.52GB and the Allocated PE occupies 4997 blocks, which is 100% of the blocks. Hence I cannot create a partition from this partition with something like `lvcreate`, such as in [this tutorial](http://www.lerrigatto.com/move-var-to-a-new-partition-with-lvm/)

So I guess my question is, where am I going wrong in this process and how do I create a partition of an arbitrary size? (let's just say 2GB to put a number on it)

Comment: Please post the output of `lvdisplay`.  It looks like `ubuntu-vg` has 2 logical volumes that use up all the space on the volume group.  Perhaps you already created var?If not, you'll need to delete or resize an existing lv to get the space for a `/var/ lv.

Comment: var is not already created, [here's lvdisplay](https://i.imgur.com/6gCyTdP.png)

Comment: So you've got an 18.5G LV for your root fs and a 1G LV for swap.  18.5G + 1G = 19.5G, which is the total size of your VG.  So you'll need to follow rsteinmetz70112's solution below to shrink the size of the root fs.  Since its the root fs, you may need to do this from a livecd (some filesystems allow an online resize, some don't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember all of operations are dangerous and you could damage your system.  You don't say what /dev/sda2 and /dev/saa3 are used for or whether they are mounted.

If you could delete the existing logical volume(s) you could create two new logical volumes in your existing volume group. That would be easy.

If you need to preserve the existing logical volume you would need to create a new logical volume within the same volume group.

To use the existing partition and volume group you need to:

1. reduce the size of the file system in the existing logical volume,
2. reduce the size of the logical volume,
3. create a new logical volume
4. make a files system in your new logical volume
5. copy your files into your new logical volumen and mount it

Where X is the size you want to reduce the existing logical volumes to, `vg=your volume group` and `lv= your logical volume` make sure you have enough empty space in you existing logical volumes that you can reduce the size. Be very careful and try it on something you can afford to mess up before doing it for real. These are very dangerous with live files systems make sure you have backups.

```
 umount /dev/mapper/vg-lv
 fsck /dev/mapper/vg-lv
 resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg-lv (X-1)G 
 lvreduce -L XG /dev/mapper/vg-lv 
 resize2fs  /dev/mapper/vg-lv (to fill up the lv)
 lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n lv-var vg 
 mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/lv-var
```

You will then need to copy the contents of var into you new logical volume, edit fstab and restart the system.

Another approach would be to reduce the size of your primary partition /dev/sda1 and create a new partition /dev/sda4.

to do that you would need a live session then

1. reduce the size of the file system  in /dev/sda1
2. reduce the partition size
3. create a new partition in the unallocated space.
4. create a new file system in the new partition

The tools to do that are generally `resizefs` `parted` to shrink the partition and create a new one and  `mkfs` to make the file system.

I'll leave the details of that to others. It is also very dangerous.